# Need help in converting JSON column into SQL table

Tags: sql, json, t-sql, sql-server-2008

Need help in converting JSON column into a SQL Server table.

I have a SQL Server `nvarchar(max)` column which stores JSON format values, as shown below.

I want to get the data into a table format to produce some reports.

Please check the sample data and also the expected result.

```
CREATE TABLE ##TempTable
(
    rawdata nvarchar(max)
)

INSERT INTO ##TempTable (rawdata) 
VALUES (
'[
    [
    {"key":"ID","value":"123"},
    {"key":"Name","value":"abc"},
    {"key":"Program","value":"qew"},
    {"key":"Type","value":"tyu"},
    {"key":"Section","value":"dd"},
    {"key":"Director","value":"ghghjg"},
    {"key":"Project","value":"hkhjk"},
    {"key":"Manager","value":"fghfgf"},
    {"key":"PCM","value":"gnhghj"},
    {"key":"Contractor","value":"gghgh"},
    {"key":"Client","value":"gghhg"}
    ],
    [
    {"key":"ID","value":"456"},
    {"key":"Name","value":"yui"},
    {"key":"Program","value":"gdffgf"},
    {"key":"Type","value":"ghgfjhjhj"},
    {"key":"Section","value":"jkjlkll"},
    {"key":"Director","value":"uiop"},
    {"key":"Project","value":"rtyuui"},
    {"key":"Manager","value":"rfv"},
    {"key":"PCM","value":"ujmk"},
    {"key":"Contractor","value":"rfvtg"},
    {"key":"Client","value":"efgg"}
    ]
]'
)
```

Expected result:

| ID | Name | Program | Type | Section | Director | Project | Manager | PCM | Contractor | Client |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | abc | qew | tyu | dd | ghghjg | hkhjk | fghfgf | gnhghj | gghgh | gghhg |
| 456 | yui | gdffgf | ghgf | jkjlkll | uiop | rtyuui | rfv | ujmk | rfvtg | efgg |

Thanks in advance.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why use two `[ ]` array? and where is your tried query? your question should be clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You have doubly-nested JSON arrays.**

The first level, containing an entire array of key/value pairs, represents a single row in the final results. We can use `OPENJSON` to break out the array, and `APPLY` it back to the original table.

The second level has key/value pairs containing column names and values. We need to pivot this within another `APPLY`.

```sql
SELECT j2.*
FROM TempTable t
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(t.rawdata) j1
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT *
    FROM OPENJSON(j1.value)
      WITH (
        [key] varchar(50),
        value varchar(100)
      ) j2
    PIVOT (
        MAX(value) FOR [key] IN (
          ID,Name,Program,[Type],Section,Director,Project,Manager,PCM,Contractor,Client
        )
    ) pvt
) j2
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/1226b/4)

Comment: Thanks for this @Charlieface :-) much appreciated.

Comment: have one more request for you. Is there a way to reverse the process meaning, how convert the above table into the above json format?

Comment: That's a new question. But rough idea would be: inside an `APPLY` to unpivot each row as `key` `value` pair, and aggregate it using `FOR JSON PATH`, then aggregate the whole thing again using `FOR JSON PATH`